# Changing the 'Page Layout' in bulk? (for every single page)

Tags: page-layout

I've just created quite literally hundreds of subsites, and need to change the Page -> default(default) page type to something other than the standard.

Is there anyway to change all of these in one go, or will I need to go through and change each one manually? At the moment it's set to 'Summary Links' and I need it to be changed to our own custom layout.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can this be of any help?

[Powershell script for updating a publishing page Page Layout in a site collection](http://jakejacobsen.wordpress.com/2011/04/06/powershell-script-for-updating-page-layouts-in-a-site-collection/)

It is basically PS script that changes page layout from one type to another. Most likely you will need to modified it a little but core is there.